# How to display the slider which is clicked after navigating to the same page after page reload in Jssor image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I am using Jssor image slider in my application. the requirement is when the user clicks an image with index number 5, the user is navigated to any other page. When the user goes back to the slider page, same image should be displayed (i.e image with index number 5)instead of image with index number 1.

I am using query string to get the index number of the clicked image.

```
 var sbIndex = '<%= Request.QueryString["SubIndex"]%>'; 
 $('#jssor_2').$GoTo = sbIndex;
```

Can anyone give me a solution to get the index number of image which is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jssor, I just took a look at it.  Anyway, it looks like jssor should not conflict with my answer.

You can put the index in the url, so when the client reloads, you read that index and set it.  The way to do this, is putting a # in the url.  Anything that is changed at the right hand side of the # will not cause a page reload, so this is a nice place to put variables meant for javascript.

Let me show a simple example of the principle.  It's a photo gallery, the photos are Brussels sprouts.

```
<div id="buttons"></div>
<img id="image" src="">
<script>
// these are images of Brussels Sprouts
var images = [
  'https://d2t35vvdhj0e6p.cloudfront.net/m/i/brussels_sprouts.jpg',
  'http://www.polskafoods.com/sites/all/sites/default/files/images/brussels-sprouts-polish-recipe.jpg',
  'http://www.onlyfoods.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Brussels-Sprouts.jpg',
  'http://www.qvm.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Brussel-Sprouts.jpg',
  'https://www.smartkitchen.com/assets/images/resources/large/1281295928Brussels%20Sprouts.jpg'
];

function generateButton(index) {
  return '<input type="button" value="' + index + '" onclick="goto(' + index + ')" />';
}
function goto(index) {
  if(images[index]) {
    // set the url
    location = '#' + index;
    // set the image source
    document.getElementById('image').src = images[index];
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var index = 0;
  // check if any index is in the url
  if(Number(location.hash.substr(1))) {
    index = Number(location.hash.substr(1));
  }
  var buttons = '';
  for(var i in images)  {
    buttons += generateButton(i);
  }
  document.getElementById('buttons').innerHTML = buttons;
  goto(index);
}
</script>
```